# JMS - one queue and many receivers (consumers)

Tags: jms, consumer

I have a JMS queue published by a third party. 
I want to setup multiple consumers on different machines, with only one particular machine's consumer, acknowledging messages on that queue. In short, if a particular machine's consumer does not receive the message, then that message should not be removed from queue.
Is this achievable ?

Comment: Don't know for what reason, I thought all consumers must receive a message but only one specific consumer will acknowledge that message. If that is not the case, why do you want to have multiple consumers for the same queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you might have your reasons for this setup and it's easy to achieve.

I would go with local session transactions. It is rather easy to commit or rollback the transactions acording to some critera, such as which server is consuming the message. If rolled back, the message will end up first in the queue again.

Sample code might look like this:

```
public class MyConsumer implements MessageListener{ 
  Session sess;

  public void init(Connection conn, Destination dest){
    // connection and destination from JNDI, or some other method.
    sess = conn.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    MessageConsumer cons = sess.createConsumer(dest);
    cons.setMessageListener(this);
    conn.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void onMessage(Message msg) {
    // Do whatever with message
    if(isThisTheSpecialServer()){
       sess.commit();
    }else{
       sess.rollback();
    }
   }

   private boolean isThisTheSpecialServer(){
      // figure out if this server should delete messages or not
   }
}
```

If you are doing this inside a Java EE container with JTA and you are using UserTransactions, you could just call UserTransaction.setRollBack();
or if you are using declarative transactions you could just throw a Runtime exception to make the transaction fail and rollback the message to the queue, once you have read the message and done things. Note that database changes will roll back as well with this approach (if you are using JTA and not local JMS transactions).

UPDATE:

You should really do this using transactions, not acknowledgement.

A summary of this topic (for ActiveMQ, but written generally for JMS) is found here.
http://activemq.apache.org/should-i-use-transactions.html

I don't know if this behaviour is consistent with all JMS implementations, but for ActiveMQ if you try to use a non transacted session with Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT, then it will not really behave as you expect. A message that has been read, but not acknowledged, is still on the queue, but will not get "released" and delivered to other JMS consumers until the connection is broken to the first consumer (i.e. connection.close(), a crash or similar).

Using local transactions, you can controll this by session.commit() and session.rollback() explicitly. I see no real point in not using transactions. Acknowledgement is just there to guarantee delivery.

Comment: FYI: Rolling back will increase the JMSXDeliveryCount. JMS Queues are configured to move the messages to a backout queue once the JMSXDeliveryCount reaches a threshold.

Comment: Using transactions here does not help you in anyway, other than making sure you're joining a JTA transaction from end to end.

Comment: Sure, but backout threshold of delivery count can probably be configured (depending on vendor). The question is still to vauge to give the full picture.

Comment: @JohnAment, of course, if you roll back the transaction and no backout queue is taking the message, it will get available to other consumers. Of course, it's better to do proper routing of the messages, but I can't see the full picture here.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at this is in the case of a forwarding queue.  You could apply it to your design by doing the following:

1. Create a consumer on the published queue from the third party.
2. This consumer has one job - distribute every message to other queues.
3. Create additional queues that your real subscribers will listen to.
4. Code your message listener to take each message and forward it to the various destinations.
5. Change each of your listeners to read from their specific queue.

By doing this, you ensure that every listener sees every message, every transaction works as expected, and you don't make any assumptions about how the message is being sent (for example, what if the publisher side is doing `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` ?)